# How to create a list of index with identical elements?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list with many vectors (VC) and I want to get a list of group of index of equal elements (VC_gr) and I think the easy part is to get a list with the values not identical(VC_val).

I have seen that collections.counter can make something similar but just with single elements.

```
VC = [[54, 57, 58], [57, 58, 61], [54, 57, 58], [72, 69, 75], [66, 68, 68], [61, 64, 66], [66, 68, 68], [66, 68, 68], [66, 68, 68], [72, 69, 75], [54, 57, 58], [72, 69, 75]]

VC_gr = [[0, 2, 10], [1], [3, 9, 11], [4, 6, 7, 8], [5]]

VC_val = [[54, 57, 58], [57, 58, 61], [72, 69, 75], [66, 68, 68], [61, 64, 66]]
```

I hope someone could help with some clue to solve this task. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
VC = [[54, 57, 58], [57, 58, 61], [54, 57, 58], [72, 69, 75], [66, 68, 68], [61, 64, 66], [66, 68, 68], [66, 68, 68], [66, 68, 68], [72, 69, 75], [54, 57, 58], [72, 69, 75]]

VC_gr = []
VC_val = []

seen = []
for v in VC:
    if v not in VC_val:
        VC_val.append(v)

    rv = []
    for i2, j in enumerate(VC):
        if v == j and i2 not in seen:
            rv.append(i2)
            seen.append(i2)
    if rv:
        VC_gr.append(rv)

print(VC_gr)
print(VC_val)
```

Prints:

```
[[0, 2, 10], [1], [3, 9, 11], [4, 6, 7, 8], [5]]
[[54, 57, 58], [57, 58, 61], [72, 69, 75], [66, 68, 68], [61, 64, 66]]
```